# How to check if Media Controls notification is present

Tags: android, notifications

On Android >11, I want to check if the [Media Controls](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-controls) notification is present.

I already have a `NotificationListenerService`, with

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.notification.default_filter_types"
            android:value="ongoing|conversations|alerting|silent" />
```

It reacts to notifications and `activeNotifications` returns most notifications. Media Controls don't appear in this list and no event gets triggered when they appear/disappear/change.

I also tried `MediaSessionManager::getActiveSessions`, which returns all the sessions that show Media Controls, *but* also returns some that don't (or those that sometimes show Media Controls, and sometimes don't).

Answer (score 0):

The Media Controls notification is correctly found, as any other notification is, in a release build.